# Why does my ajax request dont sends to the written url?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

In my app, when I click the button it should send ajax request to the given url, but it doesnt work.

My form in .blade.php file

```
<form id="RegisterForm" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="password2" id="password2"> <br>
    <button id="registerBtn">SEND</button>
</form>
```

JS file

```
$('#registerBtn').click(function(event){
        e.preventDefault(event);
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        var name = $("#username").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();

        $.ajax({
           url:"{{ url('/registrate') }}",
           method: 'post',
           data:{name:name, email:email},
           success:function(data){
              alert(data.success);
           }
        });
    });
```

URLS in my web.php

```
Route::GET('/register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegiserForm');
Route::POST('/registrate', 'Auth\AuthController@registerUser');
```

AuthController

```
public function showRegiserForm(){
    return view('register');
}

public function registerUser(Request $req){
    $name = $req->input('name');
    $email = $req->input('email');
    echo $name .  ' ' . $email;
    return view('homepage');
}
```

I think that the problem is that it sends request to the

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/register
```

Not to the /registrate, But in ajax request I use /registrate. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

A JS file is a static resource and won't process blade template syntax (or any php)

Change

```
 url:"{{ url('/registrate') }}",
```

To

```
 url:'/registrate',
```

Comment: well, nothing changed. Triggers "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD." Which means that this is still sending to the /register not to the /registrate

Comment: Look at request itself in browser dev tools network. Don't see how it would go to different url than the one coded unless you have a cache issue

Comment: Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/register
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: ok..then do a hard refresh and make sure you have updated js version loading

Comment: what is hard refresh? and how to do it?

Comment: Keys `CTRL + F5` or `CMD + F5` for mac

Comment: Have you re-run `npm run dev`?

Answer (score 0):

In your blade file, declare a variable for the `registrate` url in a `<script>` tag

form.blade.php

```
<script>
    var registrateUrl = {{ url('/registrate')}};
</script>
```

then in the JS file, use that variable.

```
$.ajax({
    url: registrateUrl,
    method: 'post',
    data:{name:name, email:email},
    success:function(data){
       alert(data.success);
    }
});
```